# Is there a way to store a series of strings into an array with a specific offset in Mips?

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

(I'm very new to Mips and I understand that some of my syntax and / or logic might seem weird or is incorrect. Thank you for understanding).

I've been asked to read a series of strings from the user into an array created by allocating space within the program. Inside of my get_input function, I pass the address of the array and the character buffer size for when I use syscall 8 to read string.

The get_input function stores the inputted string, (maximum of 32 characters), and then passes it into the strtrunc function to truncate the string with a $zero value at the end. The strtrunc funciton also counts the size of the word and saves the value onto $v0.

At this point, the program returns to the get_input function and saves the value from $v0 into the lengths array, followed by increasing the offsets for the arrays used.

I'm running into a series of problems with storing the inputted word and later accessing it—Originally, I was using an offset of four for my word array to store the words, however, entering a word with more than four characters would push the remaining characters onto the next offset.

Example (Inputting Thanks): [n a h T][ \0 \0 s k], followed by the loop while entering "Again" overlaps the previous characters: Example (After inputting Again): [n a h T][ i a g A][\0 \0 \0 n] Which is why I've adding an offset of the size of the previous word + 1 for the $zero we added in the strtrunc function.

I guess the question is more geared towards how I'm choosing to save the user inputted string into the array. Am I doing this incorrectly? I'm later supposed to read the inputted strings backwards, however, I can only correctly read the first string inputted into the program. (I'm not including that function as that problem can be solved fairly easily). Lastly, I can correctly access the lengths array and the values stored with an offset of four. It's just the character / string array that I can't access correctly. I would love to have the same offsets of four for the address of the string, while still storing the whole string without it being overwritten by the following word.

[s k n a h T][n i a g A]

0x0000     0x0004

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter up to 16 strings (max 31 characters) 1 per line\nEnter a blank line to finish inputing the strings.\n"
prompt1: .asciiz "Next string: "

.align 2
strings: .space 512  #16 strings of up to 32 characters each including the null character

.align 2
lengths: .space 64 #Space for 16 values for the length

.text
main:
    # Step 1: Read user-inputted strings
    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    #Call get_input
    la $a0, prompt1
    la $a1, strings
    li $a2, 32
    jal get_input
    
    # Step 2: Calculate string lengths
    #Already done from get_input and stored into the Lengths Array
    
exit_main:
    li   $v0, 10            # 10 is the exit program syscall
    syscall             # execute call


###############################################################
# Grabs the inputted strings and saves to strings array.
#$a0 - address of prompt to print
#$a1 - address to store string
#$a2 - Max string length
#$s0 - Loop counter
#$t3 - Offset to store information
#$t4 - Load the byte for exit loop
#$t5 - Lengths Array Offset
get_input:
    subi $sp, $sp, 4 #Push return address onto the stack to save it
    sw $ra, ($sp)
    li $s0, 0   #initalize counter variable
    li $t3, 0   #initalize offset variable
    li $t5, 0   #Initalize offset variable
    
get_input_loop:
    beq $s0, 16, end_get_input #Loop statement check
    la $a0, prompt1
    li $v0, 4   #Syscall for prompt text
    syscall
    
    la $a0, strings($t3)    #$a1 has the location to store the string, move that into $a0 for the read word syscall
    move $a1, $a2       #$a2 has the maximum character buffer, move that into $a1 for the read word syscall
    li $v0, 8
    syscall
                #$a0 now has the inputted word—We want to manipulate. Trucnate and then store the word inside of the array.
    lbu $t4, ($a0)      #Check to see if the inputted word is null or just a space
    beq $t4, $zero, end_get_input   #If so, exit loop
    
                #Trunc the string
    jal strtrunc
    beq $t4, 0x20, end_get_input #If the inputted byte is a space, exit the loop
    
                #At this point $v0 has the length of the string and the truncatted string has been saved 
    sw $v0, lengths($t5)    #Store the length found in $v0 to lengths
    addi $t5, $t5, 4    #Add 4 to the lengths offest
    add $t3, $t3, $v0   #Add whatever the length of the last string was to the word offest 
    addi $t3, $t3, 1    #Add one more for the $zero we added in the strtrunc function
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    #Add one to the total count of the strings array

    j get_input_loop
end_get_input:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
###############################################################
#Truncate string at newline character.
#$a0 - address of string
#Returns
#$v0 - Length of string
strtrunc:
    move $t0, $zero
    move $t1, $a0
str_loop:
    lbu $t2, ($t1)          #Character at a spot in the word
    beq $t2, 0x20 end_strtrunc  #If the byte is a space
    beq $t2, 0xA end_strtrunc
    beq $t2, 0x0 end_strtrunc
        addi $t0, $t0, 1    #Length of string
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    #Byte offset
    j str_loop
    
end_strtrunc:
    sb $zero, ($t1)
    move $v0, $t0
    jr $ra
```

Comment: You're packing all the strings together into the string space.  Thus, to access the 2nd string, you have to add the length of the first string (+1 for the null), and to access the 3rd string you have to either know the address of the 2nd string and add its length + 1, or start over from the first, and add both the 1st strings's length and 2nd strings length (+nulls).

Comment: But you're not showing any code after `jal get_input`, so what is your question?

Comment: Separately from the character data, you could store an array of pointers to the start of each string, so you can randomly index into it.  Like C `char *argv[]`

Answer (score 0):

Erik Eidt Provided me with a very straightforward answer—I was hoping that I wouldn't necessarily have to iterate based on the size / length of the previous string, however, this is the only valid method that I can implement at the moment with my current knowledge.
Since I'm storing all of the strings into my array, I can iterate to the second string based on the first string's size +1. To reach the third string I'd have to know the second string's address and iterate based on the second string's size.